# C# Xaml (Windows Universal App) open new Page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to re-do my old windows form project in Windows Universal app.
I need to open another windows, in my old project:
`WindowsForm2 frm = new WindowsForm2();
frm.ShowDialog(); // or .Show()`
in my new project I can't use the "Show()" method. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigate-between-two-pages

In UWP you should use Frame class to navigate between pages:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
```

Also moving to new page and opening a new window are two different things. Second one is a little harder:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/show-multiple-views